# ip address hidden in contact forms

Tags: forms, ip

i am using the following code to get ip during form submission:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function getIP(json) {
    document.getElementById("ipaddress").value = json.ip;
}
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

The code is working and I am getting the IP address when I test it but for real spam that i am getting the IP is not shown in the email. Proxy can change the IPs but can be it totally hidden or there is something missing in the code? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the spammers are not using the webpage itself to submit the form. They are probably using some other tool to directly submit the form with, bypassing any JavaScript that you have.

In order to fix this issue, you will need to do some validation on the backend that the form is valid, as any frontend measures can be bypassed. Something like making sure the backend treats a missing IP address as an error (e.g. 400 - Bad Request) might suffice, but I would recommend looking in to some form of [CAPTCHA (Wikipedia article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) to validate real users more thoroughly.

Comment: already have google recaptcha installed and running. making sure the backend treats a missing IP address as an error seems to be a good idea. thank you